# LINQ Data Sorting

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-2.1

I am trying to fill select tag options from JQuery ajax call. I am using Asp.Net Core 2.1 Razor Pages, and PostgreSQL as DB.

Here is my Server side LINQ code

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult TypeofAccounts()
{
    var result = (from N in _POSContext.TypeOfAccounts
                  select new { label = N.AccountType, id = N.AccountType });

    return Json(result);
}
```

It works fine. Now, I want to sort those results from `LINQ` so I tried following ways but it always encounters `Npgsql` Exception `"column \"label\" does not exist"`

```
var result = (from N in _POSContext.TypeOfAccounts.OrderBy(x=>x.AccountType)
              select new { label = N.AccountType, id = N.AccountType });         

var result = (from N in _POSContext.TypeOfAccounts
              select new { label = N.AccountType, id = N.AccountType }).OrderBy(x => x.label);        

var result = (from N in _POSContext.TypeOfAccounts.OrderBy(x => x.AccountType)
               where N.AccountType != null
               select new { label = N.AccountType, id = N.AccountType });
```

I could see coloumn is missing in generated sql.

```
{SELECT x."AccountType" AS id
FROM "TypeOfAccounts" AS x
WHERE x."AccountType" IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY label}
```

Comment: Why are you mixing lambda and query syntax? Try `var result = _POSContext.TypeOfAccounts.OrderBy(x => x.AccountType).Select(n => new { label = n.AccountType, id = n.AccountType });`

Comment: With given code, Generated SQL Statement is {SELECT x."AccountType" AS id
FROM "TypeOfAccounts" AS x
ORDER BY label}. Hence no data in result.

Comment: Try this =>  var result = _POSContext.TypeOfAccounts.OrderBy(x=>x.AccountType).Select(x => new { label = x.AccountType, id = x.AccountType }).ToList();

Comment: All 3 ordering approaches look good to me.  I would examine in the debugger if result is ordered.  If it is, suspect that the Json() call is disordering the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invoke the query from the database using `ToList` method, then selecting your object, like this:

```
var result = _POSContext.TypeOfAccounts
            .Where(x => x.AccountType != null)
            .OrderBy(x => x.AccountType)
            .ToList()
            .Select(x => 
                new
                {
                    label = x.AccountType,
                    id = x.AccountType
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var result = _POSContext.TypeOfAccounts
                .Where(x => x.AccountType != null)
                .OrderBy(x => x.AccountType)
                .ToList()
                .Select(x => 
                    new
                    {
                        label = x.AccountType,
                        id = x.AccountType
                    }
                );
```

Comment: Error is "column \"label\" does not exist". I updated question, please see